# Two monitors two computers, but also use one to extend from second machine?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two desktops one windows one linux. I used to use a KVM switch to share my one monitor between both machines. I just got a 42" TV that's hooked up to my linux machine.

I'd like to be able to extend my windows monitor onto it when needed. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need dual output on the Windows machine that's compatible with the monitor and TV.

And then use a dual-monitor capable KVM, specific to your video connection types.

[Here's one from Startech](http://ca.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/2-Port-DVI-VGA-Dual-Monitor-KVM-Switch-USB-with-Audio-and-USB-20-Hub~SV231DDVDUA) for example.